# Does deleting an argo cron workflow delete all argo workflows started by it as well

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argo-cron-workflows

It looks like the case that when I delete an Argo cron workflow with `argo cron delete`, all the previous workflows (completed as well as still running ones) will also be deleted based on my observation. I'm not totally sure though and I haven't found a more detailed doc than https://argoproj.github.io/argo/cli/argo_cron_delete/.

What if I'd like to keep all the history workflows when e.g. updating the frequency of a cron workflow, e.g. to run every Monday instead of every day? What would be the recommended way to do such an update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to Michael's answer:

`CronWorkflows` are *owners* of all the `Workflows` they spawn, so how their respective `Workflows` are deleted when the parent `CronWorkflow` is deleted is governed by [Kubernetes' Garbage Collection policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/). Argo does not delete the child `Workflows` of a `CronWorkflow` when the latter is deleted, Kuebrnetes does. You can see the Kubernetes doc for more options on how to manage this.

(Edit: adding more info)

For example, to delete a `CronWorkflow` while leaving its children `Workflows` intact, you can run:

```
kubectl delete cwf my-cwf --cascade=false
```

Source: I developed the `CronWorkflow` feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep workflow data around for a while, you should persist them to a database using Argo's [workflow archive](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/docs/workflow-archive.md) tool.

Just to confirm your issue, I did a quick test using their "hello-world" cron workflow:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"   # Default to local machine timezone
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 0
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"      # Default to "Allow"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 4     # Default 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 4         # Default 1
  suspend: false                    # Set to "true" to suspend scheduling
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: whalesay
    templates:
      - name: whalesay
        container:
          image: docker/whalesay:latest
```

Deleting the cron workflow does indeed delete the hello-world workflow kicked off by it. I'm especially confident because I have other workflows that have been sitting on my Minikube cluster for days without being deleted.

If you don't want to use the workflow archive, you can use `kubectl edit cronworkflow <workflow name>`. I just tested, and the update will not delete the child workflows.

If you're using something like Kustomize or Helm, it's possible your changes might delete/recreate the cron workflows rather than simply patching them. You'd have to check the docs of those projects.

I agree, the docs should be more clear. I'd recommend opening a PR against their [`argo cron delete` page](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/fafc5a904d2e2eff15bb1b3e8c4ae3963f522fa8/docs/cli/argo_cron_delete.md).